# Strange type mismatch in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to invoke a constructor that takes a varargs in Scala. The constructor is written in a Java class and takes two parameters, a `Block` and `IBlockState...`. The following code doesn't seem to compile, however:

```
new BlockStateList(this, Seq[IBlockState[_ <: Comparable[_]]](FACING, DAMAGE):_*)
```

The compiler reports with this message:

```
Error:(58, 66) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.IBlockState[_ <: Comparable[_]]]
 required: Seq[net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.IBlockState[? <: Comparable[?0]] forSome { type ?0 <: Comparable[?0] }]
   new BlockStateList(this, Seq[IBlockState[_ <: Comparable[_]]](FACING, DAMAGE):_*)
                                      ^
```

The required type doesn't seem syntactically correct to me, and I have no idea as to what it wants me to provide.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not related to varargs, but to the content of the sequence.

As I have deduced Comparable is restricted to its type parameter. Something like

```
trait Comparable[C <: Comparable[C]]
```

See [more info](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded) about this pattern. So to denote this type requirement you need advanced [existential types](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) specification. `MyType[_]` is shortcut to full `MyType[A] forSome {type A}`. In your case compiler expects

```
Seq[IBlockState[_ <: Comparable[C]] forSome { type C <: Comparable[C] }]()
```

instead of

```
Seq[IBlockState[_ <: Comparable[_]]]()
```